# Can i install Centos from Amazon AMI image or snapshot on local computer

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have the Amazon Ec2 instance with Centos installed. I ahve all the desired plugins / modules etc installed.

Now i want to make the exact copy of that in my local computer virtual machine in vmware so that i can make that as developement server.

I ahve snapshots and AMI images on Amazon Ec2 but how can i download that and install on local computer

Answer (score 3):

You can't actually download the AMI to use it.

However, you can use The [VMWare Converter Tool](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) to accomplish the task. Leave the instance online, then use the "copy live server" feature. While designed for P2V applications it'll work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend scripting and automating the installation of all of your desired plugins and modules using a tool like [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) or [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/), and using that same tool to configure your EC2 and your local vmware instances identically. Not only does this give you consistency, it gives you repeatability and full portability with many cloud providers.

It's incredibly liberating to auto-provision production and development servers, and to test new configurations locally in vmware before launching your changes to EC2.

For instance, I have chef cookbooks that install all the yum packages I want, add special yum repositories, add users and groups, create directories, put certain files in place with the right permissions, download and compile software, configure services -- all of it. And with a few tweaks here and there the same configurations work on CentOS, Amazon Linux, and most other RHEL-ish distros. It's great to fire up a server with [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) instead of having to mess with cloud providers when I'm just testing or developing.